# Azurerm need 2 shots to destroy an Azure Key Vault

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm

**What I am doing**

I run this azurerm Terraform script:

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault" "kv" {
  name                       = "mykvfdlm"
  location                   = "westeurope"
  resource_group_name        = "croustillant"
  tenant_id                  = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  sku_name                   = "standard"
  purge_protection_enabled   = false
  soft_delete_retention_days = 7

  network_acls {
    default_action             = "Deny"
    bypass                     = "AzureServices"
  }

  access_policy {
    tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
    object_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id

    key_permissions    = ["Get", "List", "Update", "Delete", "Purge"]
    secret_permissions = ["Get", "List", "Set", "Delete", "Purge"]
  }
}

data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "secrets" {
  name         = each.key
  value        = each.value
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.kv.id
  for_each     = var.secrets
}

variable "secrets" {
  type        = map(string)
  default     = {}
}
```

It is running from a SPN having these permissions on croustillant resources group:

[image]

**My issue**

I run:

```
terraform apply
```

everything is OK

Then:

```
terraform destroy
```

Get this error message:

> │ Error: purging Key Vault (Subscription:
> "XXXXX" │ Resource Group Name:
> "croustillant" │ Key Vault Name: "mykvfdlm"): performing PurgeDeleted:
> vaults.VaultsClient#PurgeDeleted: Failure sending request:
> StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: Code="AuthorizationFailed"
> Message="The client 'XXXXX' with object
> id 'XXX' does not have authorization
> to perform action
> 'Microsoft.KeyVault/locations/deletedVaults/purge/action' over scope
> '/subscriptions/XXX' or the scope is
> invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your
> credentials."

All resource are deleted anyway, but KV not purged

If I run again:

```
terraform destroy
```

KV is purged and the command is OK

I am using:

- azurerm => 3.71.0
- terraform => 1.5.3

**What I need**

1. I don't understand why the second shot is not working. Does anybody know?
2. What I can do to make the script working with one single shot

I read the azurerm documentation:

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/key_vault_key

I have the prerequisite asked on first note

**Edit notes**

Its working when adding owner at subscription level (not Resource Group). This is not possible in our security constraints.

Thank you

Comment: @Frederic_De_Lene_Mirouze, I tried the script with all the necessary permissions. I was able to run the entire steps in a single go. Please retry running the script again. If the permissions are recently revoked at the time of running the script it will take some time to sync. I mentioned this because the error mentioned In the query was related to the permission revoke issue.

Comment: This is a long time issue.

Could you list me all the permissions you have?
Thanks

Comment: I have this permissions [link](https://i.imgur.com/ELsOS6g.png)

Comment: Have you made any progress? @Frederic_De_Lene_Mirouze

Comment: I have made some more tests and it's strange

It is working if I set owner at subscription level. But the security team will never accept this.



At resource group level as you did it does not work. Did you use a service principal?

Comment: When added owner permission on RG level, Condition is scoped as Add, not None as in your case. I don't know what it mean or if it is meaningfull

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255338/discussion-between-vinay-b-and-frederic-de-lene-mirouze).

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to destroy the Azure key vault after creating it using Terraform I was able to destroy the resource created successfully in one go.

The Terraform Azure provider cannot purge the deleted Azure Key Vault because you do not have the required permissions. You need to assign a role to the client (service principal or user) you're using for Terraform that includes the `Microsoft.KeyVault/locations/deletedVaults/purge/action` permission.

Here is a more concise version:

**Terraform Azure purge permission error**

You need the `Microsoft.KeyVault/locations/deletedVaults/purge/action` permission to purge a deleted Azure Key Vault. Assign the appropriate role to the Terraform client.

To resolve this issue, you should ensure that the Azure service principal or user account being used by Terraform has the appropriate permissions or custom role permission to purge deleted Key Vaults. You can do this by updating the access policies for the Key Vault.

**My terraform configuration:**

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault" "kv" {
  name                       = "keyvaultvksb"
  location                   = "East US"
  resource_group_name        = "v-sakavya"
  tenant_id                  = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  sku_name                   = "standard"
  purge_protection_enabled   = false
  soft_delete_retention_days = 7

  network_acls {
    default_action             = "Deny"
    bypass                     = "AzureServices"
  }

  access_policy {
    tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
    object_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id

    key_permissions    = ["Get", "List", "Update", "Delete", "Purge"]
    secret_permissions = ["Get", "List", "Set", "Delete", "Purge"]
  }
}

data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "secrets" {
  name         = each.key
  value        = each.value
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.kv.id
  for_each     = var.secrets
}

variable "secrets" {
  type        = map(string)
  default     = {}
}
```

**Output:**

Command `Terraform_apply`

[image]

Command `Terraform_destroy`

[image]